# Is there a better way to check if a number is part of a certain sequence?

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering, if there is a better way, to check, if a certain number n is part of a specific sequence of natural numbers:

The way i think of now would iteratively/recursively compute the next number of the sequence, until you find the n. And, if a number x, bigger than n, would be computed, n would not be in the sequence, and i would stop the loop.

But this seems to be computationally quite demanding, especially if the given number is huge.

So, i was wondering, if there are fundamentally better ways (maybe another algorithmic approach) to achieve the same thing?

Comment: you could use binary search, but I don't see enough information in this post to be sure about it.

Comment: It depends. Do you know the logic behind the sequence beforehand? Or do you have to first figure out the logic?

Comment: In my case i would know the logic behind.

Comment: The algorithm you suggest only works for increasing sequences. This is a big assumption to have about a sequence, and this assumption leads to your algorithm. If you have even bigger assumptions, it could lead to even more efficient algorithms. For instance, if you know that the sequence is an arithmetic progression, it is extremely easy to check whether the number is in the sequence, without generating the terms.

Comment: I don't think there's an algorithm that works for all possible sequences **and** is reliably better than iterating. But if you know some basic details about the sequence (for example if it's monotonically increasing/decreasing) and can also compute stuff other than just the next value, then you can optimize based on those parameters (for example using a variant of binary search).

Comment: If your sequence is generated by a function `f(n)` (pure function, no side effect) you can use the binary search (with some differences) as suggested by previous comment. Sone difference as you should start looking for `f(10)`, `f(100)`, `f(1000)` and so on until you don't get a number > n and then you can apply the standard binary search. (Increase in power of 10 is first thing I thought, I think it could be optimized) last thing this would work only if you are sure your sequence is monotonically increasing

Comment: @rascio: binary search only works on sorted content. If the sequence isn't monotonically increasing or decreasing this could easily miss the number.

Comment: The bottom-line of all the comments is this: please tell us more about the sequence you are interested in!!

Comment: *IF* the sequence is a non-decreasing sequence and *IF* `S(n)` can be determined in the same time *regardless of how big `n` is*, then you can use skip-ahead/unbounded searches like an exponential search, followed by a bounded search, like binary searching once an upper limit for `n` is determined.

Comment: I was trying to keep it as general as possible. And, like others already mentioned it, it seems to be extremely dependend on the sequence at hand. I only implemented the algorithm above for monotonically increasing sequences, like the Fibonacci-Series, or Lucas-Numbers. But, i thought my way, was quite brutish. So i was wondering, how to find a maybe better approach, than computing the next numbers in the sequence, until i find the sought number.